# Admob Ads doesn't appears in real device he works only in Emulator

Tags: android, ads, admob

hi i'm trying to add admob ads **Banner** and **Interstitial** in my app i tried testads by google and works fine in real device also i tried old ads that I added in my apps and worked well . I waited more than 1h 30min but ads doens't appears.

my code :

```
private AdView mAdView;
InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     ....
     .....
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().
            build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            super.onAdClosed();
            mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.Night_int));


    @Override
public void onPause() {
    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.pause();
    }
    super.onPause();
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.resume();
    }
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

xml :

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/Night_banner"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: From my First app experiance, It will take one day to display ads on Real admob ID.

Comment: upload logs from real device. Make sure correct ad Id is set ( most common error is setting account Id to banner ID )